# With $X_{i} \stackrel{i.i.d}{\sim} Expo(\lambda)$ find probability that all $X_{i} > 60$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution

Given the following,
$$X_{i} \stackrel{i.i.d}{\sim} Expo(\lambda)$$
Find the probability that every $X_{i} > 60$. My intuition is to do the following,
$$P(X_{i} > 60) = 1 - F(60) = e^{-\lambda 60}$$
Then using the multiplication rule to find $(e^{-\lambda 60})^{n}$ where n is the number of r.v.s in $i$

Would this be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intuition for these are, if $X_1,\ldots,X_n \sim \mathrm{Expo}(\lambda)$ and they are iid, then we get

$P(\mathrm{min}(X_i)>60) = P(X_1>60 \cap \ldots \cap X_n>60)=P(X_1>60)\cdot\ldots\cdot P(X_n>60)=P(X_1>60)^n = (1-F(60))^n$

So your intuition is correct. I just wanted to show the general idea for these order statistics. Keep in mind this only works when independent and identical.

Comment: Awesome! I also found this resource which generalizes this as well. https://mast.queensu.ca/~stat455/lecturenotes/set4.pdf (page 5)

Comment: @CarterKF it's nice to keep in mind that for problems on the form for every $X_i >x$ or $X_i<x$ you can look at the distribution of the min and max respectively.This then works for any distribution, not just the exponential.